# Regex replace word in string that are not in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to do replacements in unknown third-party inputs in strings that sometimes have quotes among them.

I want to replace a wholeword whereever it occurs unless it's in double or single-quotes, and unless the quote is escaped.

Example: Replacing FOO by BAR

Input:

```
FOO "FOO" 'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"FOO\"
```

Expected output:

```
BAR "FOO" 'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"BAR\"
```

More tests:

```
name: FOO
favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."
children: 'FOO\'s children'
cars: ownersList[FOO]
statement = FOO + " is the owner of the house."
```

Expected output:

```
name: BAR
favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."
children: 'FOO\'s children'
cars: ownersList[BAR]
statement = BAR + " is the owner of the house."
```

I saw this question: [Match and replace a word not in quotes (string contains escaped quotes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274577/match-and-replace-a-word-not-in-quotes-string-contains-escaped-quotes) which I thought was similar and could be a good starting point the accepted answer does not work at all:

https://regex101.com/r/Lfan64/5

If anyone could help me get the expected result from my regex that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Why is it replacing inside single quotes: `'FOO\'s children'` ?

Comment: Try `text.replace(/((?:[^\\]|^)(?:\\{2})*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[^][^'\\]*)*'))|FOO/g, (match, group) => group || "BAR")`, see [the JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/ey2Lvhm1/).

Comment: Also `\"FOO\"` appears like invalid input because of missing real quotes (single or double)

Comment: @anubhava my mistake when copying sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = String.raw`name: FOO
favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."
children: 'FOO\'s children'
cars: ownersList[FOO]
statement = FOO + " is the owner of the house."
FOO "FOO" 'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"FOO\"`
console.log( text.replace(
  /((?:[^\\]|^)(?:\\{2})*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[^][^'\\]*)*'))|FOO/g,
  (match, group) => group || "BAR"
))
```

*Details*:

- `((?:[^\\]|^)(?:\\{2})*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[^][^'\\]*)*'))` - Group 1:

  - `(?:[^\\]|^)` - a char other than `\` or start of string
  - `(?:\\{2})*` - zero or more sequences of double backslash
  - `(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[^][^'\\]*)*')` - either of a double or single quoted string literal pattern with escape sequence support
- `|` - or
- `FOO` - a `FOO` string in any other context.

The `(match, group) => group || "BAR"` replacement means that if Group 1 matches, the replacement is Group 1 value, else, the replacement is `BAR`.

Comment: This is a bit longer than the other answer, is it more comprehensive somehow?

Comment: @Harry Longer does not mean worse. This one 1) matches even with line break chars, 2) contains no lookbehind and will work in Safari and other browsers that do not support lookbehinds, 3) will skip the leftmost `'` or `"` that are escaped.

Comment: Absolutely thanks awesome! That explanation really helped.

Comment: I think FOO needs `\b` around it.

Comment: @Harry Word boundaries are context dependent, so it is not possible to say if `\b` will work in every case. Please check [my YT video on adaptive word boundaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngbxagE2b68) to learn more about the issue.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, unfortunately it seems like lookbehinds are the way people deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your requirements correctly, you may try this regex for your cases:

```sh
((['"])(?:\\.|(?!\2).)*(?<!\\)\2)|\bFOO\b/g
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lfan64/7)

This regex uses alternation to match and discard what we need to keep on LHS of `|` whereas on RHS we match whatever we want to replace in the result.

**Code:**

```js
const str = String.raw`name: FOO
favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."
children: 'FOO\'s children'
cars: ownersList[FOO]
statement = FOO + " is the owner of the house."
FOO "FOO" 'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"FOO\"`;

var repl = str.replace(/((['"])(?:\\.|(?!\2).)*(?<!\\)\2)|\bFOO\b/g,
  (_, g) => g || "BAR");
  
console.log(repl);
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(['"])`: Match `'` or `"` in capture group #2
  - `(?:\\.|(?!\2).)*`: Match an escaped character or any character except the quote we matched in capture group #2
  - `(?<!\\)\2`: Match whatever quote we matched in capture group #2 as long as it is not preceded by a `\`
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `|`: OR
- `\bFOO\b`: Match complete word `FOO`

Comment: Your regex101 link is different from your answer right?

Comment: Oops https://regex101.com/r/Lfan64/7 should be correct one

Comment: Thanks, using that though it still doesn't seem to work on that site.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxiKZ.png

Comment: I might be using the website wrong there doesn't seem to be a selection for which match to replace

Comment: The BLUE color highlighted matches from regex101 demo will be replaced with `BAR` as you can see in Javascript demo in my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wonder if there's a regex site that can show the intended replacements.

Comment: Since this is not 100% pure regex solution (see we are using a lambda in replacement) it won't be possible for a regex demo site to show you all the replacements.