# Regex replacement only if it's in braces and not in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to do replacements in unknown third-party inputs in strings that sometimes have quotes among them. I want to replace a wholeword whereever it occurs if it's in braces `{}` or marked with {replaceinside}{/replaceinside} unless it's in double or single-quotes, and unless the quote is escaped.

Regex so far largely comes from this question: [Regex replace word in string that are not in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71016786/regex-replace-word-in-string-that-are-not-in-quotes) Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew and anubhava who helped me out there.

I thought after asking that question it would be easy to integrate the final braces requirement but guess not.

Here's my test string and the output:

```
`name: FOO
{favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."}
children: 'FOO\'s children'
{cars: ownersList[FOO]}
statement = {FOO} + " is the owner of the house."
{replaceinside}FOO "FOO" {'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ} "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"FOO\"{/replaceinside}`
```

I would like to replace FOO with BAR.
Expected Output:

```
`name: FOO
{favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."}
children: 'FOO\'s children'
{cars: ownersList[BAR]}
statement = {BAR} + " is the owner of the house."
{replaceinside}BAR "FOO" {'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ} "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"BAR\"{/replaceinside}`
```

Ultimately I would like to use the text as a template and create an array of strings with mapped replacements. Like so:

```
var v = "BAR", arr = ["BAR", "BAZ"], finalArr = [], swappedFromValue = "FOO"

const text = String.raw`
name: FOO
{favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."}
children: 'FOO\'s children'
{cars: ownersList[FOO]}
statement = {FOO} + " is the owner of the house."
{replaceinside}FOO "FOO" {'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ} "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"FOO\"{/replaceinside}
`

var replacementRegex = new RegExp('{(.*?)((?:[^\\\\]|^)(?:\\\\{2})*(?:"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[^][^"\\\\]*)*"|\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\[^][^\'\\\\]*)*\'))|\\b' + swappedFromValue + '\\b(.*?)}', 'g') // single line
var replacementInsideRegex = new RegExp('{replaceinside}(.*?)((?:[^\\\\]|^)(?:\\\\{2})*(?:"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[^][^"\\\\]*)*"|\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\[^][^\'\\\\]*)*\'))|\\b' + swappedFromValue + '\\b(.*?){/replaceinside}', 'gs') // multi line

function replaceFunc (v, k) {
  var replacedText = text.replace(replacementRegex, function (match, group) {
    return group || v;
  })
  replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacementInsideRegex, function (match, group) {
    return group || v;
  })
  finalArr.push(replacedText)
}

arr.forEach(replaceFunc)
document.body.innerHTML = finalArr.join("<br><br>")
```

Expected output:

```
`name: FOO
{favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."}
children: 'FOO\'s children'
{cars: ownersList[BAR]}
statement = {BAR} + " is the owner of the house."
{replaceinside}BAR "FOO" {'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ} "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"BAR\"{/replaceinside}

name: FOO
{favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."}
children: 'FOO\'s children'
{cars: ownersList[BAZ]}
statement = {BAZ} + " is the owner of the house."
{replaceinside}BAZ "FOO" {'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ} "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"BAZ\"{/replaceinside}`
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7016sv4/1/

Comment: With "brackets", you mean braces (`{}`)? Or also square brackets (`[]`) and parentheses `()`?

Comment: @trincot mean just braces, will fix.

Comment: What if a brace is escaped with a backslash? Or is backslash escaping only relevant for quotes?

Comment: @trincot backslash escaping is only relevant for quotes. Thanks for helping me clarify the problem.

Comment: What is the advantage of using `{replaceinside} ... FOO ... {/replaceinside}` over just `{ ... FOO ... }`? Is there a difference in the effect?

Comment: @trincot The {replaceinside} does other things that the `{}` do not in real use unrelated to replacements, therefore it exists as something that has to be managed. Also the `{}` are single line and the `{replaceinside}` are multilined.

Comment: What will happen with nested braces, like `{ { bla } FOO }`?

Comment: @trincot FOO should be replaced in that case.

Answer (score 1):

As the solution should also deal well with nested braces, and JavaScript regular expression have no recursion capability, I would suggest to move some of the logic out of the regular expression into JavaScript code. A regular expression can still be used to identify the individual parts, but some code will be needed to:

- Maintain a stack of nested braces and nested tags
- Pair balanced braces/tags
- Make the replacement conditional on a non-empty stack
- Decide how nesting of braces *and* tags should be dealt with when they *overlap*, like `{ aa {replaceinside} bb } cc {/replaceinside} dd`. For instance, braces could be thought of as ineffective inside tags.

```js
function solution(text, source, target) {
    const regex = RegExp(String.raw`(?:\\["'])+|\{\/?replaceinside\}|[{}]|(['"])(?:\\.|.)*?\1|\b${source}\b|.`, "gs");
    let stack = [];
    return input.replace(regex, function (token) {
        if (token === "{replaceinside}") {
            stack.push("{/replaceinside}");
        } else if (token === "{" && stack.at(-1) !== "{/replaceinside}") { // Braces inside tags have no meaning
            stack.push("}");
        } else if (token === stack.at(-1)) { // Pair balanced braces/tags
            stack.pop();
        } else if (token === "\n") { // Auto-close all braces
            stack = stack.filter(item => item !== "}");
        } else if (token === source && stack.length) { // Only replace within braces/tags
            return target;
        }
        return token;
    });
}

let input = String.raw`name: FOO
{favoriteQuote: "I am my own FOO."}
children: 'FOO\'s children'
{cars: ownersList[FOO]}
statement = {FOO} + " is the owner of the house."
{replaceinside}FOO "FOO" {'FOO' "    1 + FOO + 2 " ABCFOOXYZ} "  str1\"FOO\"str3'FOO'\'\'" '  str1\'FOOstr3"FOO"\"\"' \"FOO\"{/replaceinside}`;

console.log(solution(input, "FOO", "BAR"));
```